# noob question on reading integer/string inputs in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I was trying some coding challenge in Hackerank, and I was wondering how to read a line of space-separated integers using OCaml.
I know if the input integers are newline separated,
 then we could do

```
let recread_lines () =
    try line = read_line ()
    in line:: read_lines()
with End_of_file->[]
```

and then convert the list to list of int using

```
let ()= 
let input = read_lines () 
in List.map int_of_string input.
```

I also know that we can read the first integer from a line of integers by doing:

```
let n1 =Scanf.scanf " %d" (fun x -> x)
```

From C, I know scanf method scans the line looking for structure defined in the parameter and then store the scanned values into the variables. I don't see the use of (fun x->x) at the end of the scanf method in OCaml.

I don't know how to read a line of integers though, so if you can point me in the right direction, I would be able to work on those challenges!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function to read a line of space-separated integers from `stdin`:

```
let read_ints () =
    let line = read_line () in
    let ints = Str.split (Str.regexp "  *") line in
    List.map int_of_string ints
```

This function will raise `End_of_file` if there are no more lines in the input.

You can adapt the regular expression if there are actually tabs mixed with the spaces (say).

(FWIW I have found over the years that the `scanf` family of functions is prone to behaving badly in the face of unexpected input. This isn't a problem with OCaml in particular, it's the same for all languages that have `scanf`. So I haven't used `scanf` for quite a few decades.)